# Strange behavior in Uri-class (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, uri

Why does the Uri class urldecode my url that I send to its contructor and how can I prevent this?

Example (look at the querystring value "options"):

```
    string url = "http://www.example.com/default.aspx?id=1&name=andreas&options=one%3d1%26two%3d2%26three%3d3";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url); // http://www.example.com/default.aspx?id=1&name=andreas&options=one=1&two=2&three=3
```

Update:

```
// ?id=1&name=andreas&options=one%3d1%26two%3d2%26three%3d3
Request.QueryString["options"] = one=1&two=2&three=3

// ?id=1&name=andreas&options=one=1&two=2&three=3
Request.QueryString["options"] = one=1
```

This is my problem :)

Comment: what is `QueryString`? and where is now `Request` coming from? Down 1!

Comment: Sorry, Request comes from the HttpContext object (Page_Load inside a aspx.cs using WebForms). Thought that was obvius :) I'm using it to illustrate that when you access a asp.net-page with the different url:s then you get two different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why exactly?
you can get to the encoded version using `url.AbsoluteUri`

**EDIT**

```
Console.WriteLine("1) " + uri.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine("2) " + uri.Query);

OUT:
1) http://www.example.com/default.aspx?id=1&name=andreas&options=one%3d1%26two%3d2%26three%3d3
2) ?id=1&name=andreas&options=one%3d1%26two%3d2%26three%3d3
```

Comment: Becouse the Uri changes the "options" value from "one%3d1%26two%3d2%26three%3d3" too "one=1&two=2&three=3". I shouldn't have to use any other function that ToString to get the original address?

Comment: are you interessted in the whole uri or do you want to use only the query?

Comment: updated the question. the problem is that the two url:s gives different values in Request.Querystring - that can't be a correct behavior?

Comment: If I look at the edit you made, then that means that I should NEVER use ToString() on a Uri since it shows the wrong url? Why would it even return something like that then and not just the class name like every other class that doesn't have something meaningfull to return?

Comment: `Gets a canonical string representation for the specified Uri instance.` thats from the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx! RTFM! ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But I don't get why the .NET guys decided that changing the url is a correct behavior. Becouse it changes the complete meaning of the url (querystring doesn't return the same values anymore). Anyhow I mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that from a Uri class. I am quite sure that it still gets you in a good place if you use it with e.g. WebClient class (i.e. WebClient.OpenRead (Uri uri)). What's the problem in your case?

Comment: Why would you expect the Uri to CHANGE your url? Look at my updated question - it changes the querystring to return something else (or leave some of it behind)

Comment: It does not change it. The url that you provide is urlencoded, so it decodes it, to get a Uri :). I still don't get the problem even after the update...

Comment: But the url is not urlencoded, the parameter in the querystring is urlencoded. When the complete url is urldecoded it changes the meaning of the url. But i have accepted that the .NET guys thinks this is logical (even though I don't agree to the behavior).

Answer (score 0):

This is how the internal code of .NET behaves - in previous versions you could use another constructor of `Uri` that accepted boolean value telling if to escape or not, but it has been deprecated.

The only way around it is hackish: accessing some private method directly by means of reflection:

```
string url = "http://www.example.com/default.aspx?id=1&name=andreas&options=one%3d1%26two%3d2%26three%3d3";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
MethodInfo mi = uri.GetType().GetMethod("CreateThis", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (mi != null)
    mi.Invoke(uri, new object[] { url, true, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute  });
```

This worked for me in quick test, but not ideal as you "hack" into .NET internal code.